# ShinyDashboard not supporting bootstrapPage...Updating UI does not work from htmloutput to shinydashboard

Tags: r, shiny, shiny-server, shinydashboard

I am trying to use multiple UI in my code. but with shinydashboard library changing ui using bootstrapPage doesn't work.

Previously, I was using a HTML template for login page and was trying to redirect to dashboard after login. that was not working with shinydashboard. Now I have changed the code slightly and am using "shiny" in login page and "shinydashboard" in dashboard page. But it does not work. Please refer to code below:-

## Code--

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
Logged = FALSE;
my_username <- "temp"
my_password <- "temp"

ui1 <- function(){
  tagList(
    div(id = "login",
        wellPanel(textInput("userName", "Username"),
                  passwordInput("passwd", "Password"),
                  br(),actionButton("Login", "Log in"))),
    tags$style(type="text/css", "#login {font-size:10px;   text-align: left;position:absolute;top: 40%;left: 50%;margin-top: -100px;margin-left: -150px;}")
  )}

ui2 <- function(){
  tagList(
    dashboardPage(
      dashboardHeader(title = "MY Dashboard"),
      dashboardSidebar(    
        sidebarMenu(
          menuItem("Temp_Menu", tabName = "Temp_Menu", icon = icon("bar-chart"))
        )),
      dashboardBody(
        tabItems(
          # Tab content
          tabItem(tabName = "Temp_Menu",
                  fluidRow(
                    sidebarLayout(
                      sidebarPanel(
                        selectInput("Dropdown1","Options:",c("abc","jkl","xyz"),selected = "abc"),
                        fileInput(inputId = "file1", label = "Upload File:", 
                                  accept=c(
                                    "text/csv",
                                    "text/comma-separated-values,text/plain",
                                    ".csv","sas7bdat")),
                        actionButton("go","Go!"),
                        downloadButton('downloadData', 'Download')
                      ),
                      
                      # Show a plot of the generated distribution
                      mainPanel(
                        tabsetPanel(
                          tabPanel("Tab1"), 
                          tabPanel("Tab2")
                        )
                      )
                    )
                  )
          )
        )
      ),
      skin = "blue"
    )
  )  
}

ui = (htmlOutput("page"))
server = (function(input, output,session) {
  
  USER <- reactiveValues(Logged = Logged)
  
  observe({ 
    if (USER$Logged == FALSE) {
      if (!is.null(input$Login)) {
        if (input$Login > 0) {
          Username <- isolate(input$userName)
          Password <- isolate(input$passwd)
          Id.username <- which(my_username == Username)
          Id.password <- which(my_password == Password)
          if (length(Id.username) > 0 & length(Id.password) > 0) {
            if (Id.username == Id.password) {
              USER$Logged <- TRUE
            } 
          }
        } 
      }
    }    
  })
  observe({
    if (USER$Logged == FALSE) {
      
      output$page <- renderUI({
        div(class="outer",do.call(bootstrapPage,c("",ui1())))
      })
    }
    if (USER$Logged == TRUE) 
    {
      output$page <- renderUI({
        div(class="outer",shinyUI(do.call(bootstrapPage,c(ui2()))))
      })
    }
  })
})

runApp(list(ui = ui, server = server))
```

When I use Ui2 directly, It works:-

```
runApp(list(ui = ui2, server = server))
```

But not with login page...Am I doing something wrong????

Comment: Any help on this highly appreciated....Do anyone know how to change UI....or use Html UI with shinydahboard...????

Comment: I am having the exact same issue. Please let me know if you find a solution.